# Mac iWork Pages: How can I create internal links?

Tags: macos, iwork, iwork-pages

Mac iWork Pages:  How can I create internal links?

I mean, such as one word, as a link, it can lead me go to other page which I set before. (All in one .pages file)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Double click the desired destination word, and then use Insert > Bookmark to define a bookmark.

Go to the word or phrase you want to send you to the spot above, and in the Inspector window under the Link section, check the box 'enable as a hyperlink'.  Choose the destination as a bookmark, the same one you created earlier.  The Inspector window is available (if it's not automagically open) by pressing the (i) button on the toolbar.

Here's a screenshot of the inspector:

[image]

Once more, just highlight the word you want to use as a link, and then use the inspector to set the link destination as a bookmark.

Comment: `Insert > Bookmark` no longer exists in Pages 5.2, which does not seem to support Bookmarks any longer. :(

Comment: Yep, not available in 5.2.2